# Google Cloud Build: error while creating mount source path - mkdir /workspace: read-only file system

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

One of my Google Cloud Build steps is (simplified):

```yaml
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    id: step-1
    entrypoint: bash
    args: ["./toolbelt.sh"]
```

And inside the `toolbelt.sh` is the following (simplified):

```sh
...
...

docker build \
  --platform linux/amd64 \
  --build-arg USER=$USER \
  --file build.Dockerfile \
  --quiet \
  --tag my_image ../ 

docker run \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --volume /workspace/foo/:/app/foo \
  --tty \
my_image
```

But I am getting the following error from the `cloud-build-local` tool:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/workspace/foo': mkdir /workspace: read-only file system.
```

---

The `/workspace` directory contains all of my repository files. Is it possible to volume map the `foo` sub-directory into the container like this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with help from [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dmcguire81/c9e8c20248ec1f7f6cc656fbae124d4d)

When using `cloud-build-local`, you must invoke like this:

```
cloud-build-local \
-dryrun=false \
-config=cloudbuild.yaml \
-substitutions _MOUNT_NAME=`pwd` \
-bind-mount-source \
.
```

And then send `_MOUNT_NAME` into the shell script instead of `/workspace`:

```yaml
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker"
    id: step-1
    entrypoint: bash
    env:
      - '_MOUNT_NAME=${_MOUNT_NAME}'
    args: ["./toolbelt.sh"]
```

And in the shell script:

```sh
...
...

docker build \
  --platform linux/amd64 \
  --build-arg USER=$USER \
  --file build.Dockerfile \
  --quiet \
  --tag my_image ../ 

docker run \
  --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  --volume ${_MOUNT_NAME}/foo/:/app/foo \
  --tty \
my_image
```